# Visual Studio: Unexpected PDB error; RPC (23)

Tags: visual-studio, linker-errors, pdb-files

I use Visual Studio 2019 16.10.3 and my solution contains about 150 C++ projects. Starting from some update of the studio, I receive very frequently
compilation errors as follows:

```
fatal error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '24'
```

or linking errors:

```
fatal error LNK1318: Unexpected PDB error; RPC (23) '(0x00000005)'
```

or

```
fatal error LNK1318: Unexpected PDB error; RPC (23) '(0x000006BA)
```

or

```
fatal error LNK1318: Unexpected PDB error; OK (0) ''
```

I have absolutely no cue, what provokes such errors. Just rebuilding does not resolve them, neither restarting the studio helps. The only solution that helps is restarting Windows, which is rather painful to do frequently.

Is there anyone who faced similar errors? Could you give any piece of advice how to solve or at least work around them?

Comment: Tells you that mspdbsrv.exe unexpectedly crashed.  Bits of what-the-heck  [are here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c1090-pdb-api-call-failed-error-code-23/48897).  Focusing on machine stability is paramount, start by disabling security software and cloud storage utilities.  Use 64-bit build tools next.

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestions. I uninstalled Dr. Web antivirus returning to Windows built-in Defender. It looks like the frequency of such errors is decreased but not ceased completely.

Comment: I terminated link.exe in Task Manager and reran build, everything completed fine this time.

Comment: I noticed that I get this occasionally when compiling inside visual studio, but never when compiling using MSVC as compiler/linker, but cmake to control the compilation process. It's faster, too.

Answer (score -1):

i received same error:
"LINK : fatal error LNK1318: Unexpected PDB error; RPC (23) '(0x000006BA)' .... "

i simply rebuilt the solution and it resolved the problem.

So, i suggest to build again.